# DebugDiag vs AdPlus

Tags: windbg, adplus

I have never used DebugDiag but just wondering if it offer any advantages over taking a process dump over Adplus? Or if it has any limitations that I should consider in taking snapshot.

**UPDATE:**
Doing some reading about it, seem like DebugDiag need to be installed on machine where you want go generate a dump. Certainly not a easy thing to do on client data-centres. Whereas Adplus can be Xcopied.

Comment: I do not see any advantages or limitations using one over the other for taking dumps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it answers the original question, but in regards to the update, if you want something that is easy to install on client systems to take a dump you should us [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) from sysinternals

Answer (score 0):

The dumps from DebugDiag is OK from my experience, contains heap and handles as far as I remember. 
I use DebugDiag when hunting for memory leak, because it has some good statistics on memory consumption.

Comment: Question is not about if DebugDiag dumps are ok or not. Its really a comparison bewteen dumps taken via DebugDiag vs AdPlus

Answer (score 0):

DebugDiag tool affects your application performance. If your application is not concerned of performance affect, it is a very good tool. You can also customize it with VB programming.

If anyone need help on programming it to customize, email me... I am happy to assist.